# How can I simulate long press on a view (for example Hardkey for 10 sec) using AndroidViewClient?

Tags: androidviewclient

How can I long press a hard key or keyevent for 20 seconds . Below is my code

## longPress hardkey for 10 seconds

device. longPress(‘KEYCODE_CALL’ , 10)
 Please anyone can help me for solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

The 2 accepted forms would be

```
device.longPress(‘KEY_CALL’, 10)
```

or

```
device.longPress(‘CALL’, 10)
```

and they should send the long press with 10 secs duration.

To be sure it is working check the output of

```
$ adb shell
sailfish:/ $ getevent
...
```

to check the event is sent correctly.

If it doesn't work, it might be that your device node is different, so press the key manually and see `getevent` output

```
/dev/input/event4: 0001 0072 00000001
/dev/input/event4: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event4: 0001 0072 00000000
/dev/input/event4: 0000 0000 00000000
```

and then you can use it in your script, like

```
device.longPress(‘CALL’, 10, dev='/dev/input/event4')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Above code is not working 
Actually My Application is FM where i can do long SEEK UP action using keyevent "KEYCODE_SEEK_UP" below is my exact code

device.longPress("KEYCODE_SEEK_UP", 10,dev='/dev/input/event1')

only 0.5 sec only longpress is working

Comment: by doing device.longPress(‘KEYCODE_SEEK_UP’, 10) or device.longPress(‘CALL’, 10)
also not working can u please help for solving this issue